# Brake lever compatibility between disc and v brake

Tags: brakes, brake-levers

I bought a used bike that had no front brake lever or caliper.  I am putting this one on[Caliper](https://amzn.to/2X7LBWL)
and am wondering if I can use a lever from a v brake.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. They both require the same amount of [cable pull](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1402/mechanical-bicycle-brake-compatibility/).